# Converting a DateInterval to variable integer in php

Tags: php

For Example:

```
echo $interval->format('%h.%i Hours');
```

I want to store it in integer.
How do i do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: What? You want to store the `time`(e.g. 12:30) in a integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P2Y4DT6H8M');
$str = $interval->format('%d:%h:%i:%s');
list($days, $hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $str);
$elapsedSeconds =  ($days*86400) + ($hours*3600) + ($minutes*60) + $seconds;
echo $elapsedSeconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime :

`echo strtotime('2012-03-27 18:47:00');` //--> which results to 1332866820